# c3.js: Hide dots in the series based on gap/null values

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, stream, c3.js

I'm trying to replicate a chart from a certain service using their API, I have a problem with showing the gaps. So every now and then stream is not giving info for certain sources and I handled that by putting null value in column and connectNull: false.

But there's a scenario where the values are isolated by nulles

```
[null, 66, null]
```

So nothing happes because dots are hidden, but I want to show this value.
I was thinking of using css for force opacitiy:1 on that certain dots but I have no way of detecting them. Any advice?

```
self.chart = c3.generate({
    bindto: d3.select('#' + self.chartDivId),
    data: {
        x: 'x',
        xFormat: self.options.xAxisTimeFormat,
        columns: self.chartDataSet,
    },
    line: {
        connectNull: ???
    },
    point: {
        show: ???
    },
    tooltip: {
        show: true,
        grouped: true
    },
    axis: {
        x: {
            type: 'timeseries',
            tick: {
                fit: false,
                format: self.options.xAxisTimeFormat,
                localtime: false
            }
        },
        y: {
            min: 0,
            tick: {
                fit: false,
                format: function(d) {
                    return self.yFormatter(d);
                },
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: instead of null just give 0 and try.

Comment: It will connect to 0 value, I need to aknowledge the gap in the source updates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this onrendered routine to your chart declaration. It looks for all the c3-circles classes (the points for each data series) and then tests the data associated with them for isolated data points. These are then used to set opacity on the relevant individual circles (points).

```
onrendered: function () {
    var circles = d3.select("#chart").selectAll(".c3-circles");
    circles.each (function (d) {
        var isolates = d.values.filter (function(obj, i) {
            var precedeNull = (i === 0 || d.values[i-1].value === null);
            var followingNull = (i === d.values.length-1 || d.values[i+1].value === null);
            return precedeNull && followingNull;
        });
        var indexSet = d3.set (isolates.map (function (iso) { return iso.index; }));
        d3.select(this).selectAll("circle.c3-circle").style("opacity", function (d,i) {
            return indexSet.has(i) ? 1 : 0;    
        });
    })
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ht2nrmg7/ - full fiddle